# How to set multiple folder icons in finder (for symbol- and list-view)?

Tags: macos, finder, folders, icon

I'm using OS X 10.8.2. By default the system folder icons differ in symbol- and list-view in the finder. If I use the list view a small icon (16x16px) is displayed. In symbol view finder switches to a 128x128px icon.

How can I define **both** of these icons with my custom images?

Answer (score 1):

To change a folder's icon just:

1. Open the image you want to use as icon, (with Preview, for instance). Select it all, or the part of it you want to use, and **Copy** it ( <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ).
2. Right click on the folder and choose **Show Info** ( <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> ).
3. Select the folder icon image, and **Paste** ( <kbd>Commdand</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).

[image]

Doing it this way, no matter in which view you'll be displaying the folder, the icon will be the image you've pasted.